# Should I use "happen" or "happens"?

Tags: verb-agreement

Should I use *happen* or *happens* in the following sentence:

> Everything in life, even events that seem insignificant when they occur, **happens/happen** for a reason.

I am confused because *everything* is singular, but *events* is plural.

Comment: *Everything* takes a singular verb. Remove the parenthetical insertion "even events..." and you need *happens.* You could remove any apparent ambiguity by keeping it all singular: "Everything in life, even an event that seems insignificant when it occurs, happens for a reason."

Answer (score 3):

'Events' is just an additional information, just like in the following sentence,

> "He, along with his friends, is coming to the party"

*'along with his friends'* is an additional information and verb is used according to the first word. 
Similarly, *'even events...'* is an additional information and hence verb will be used according to 'everything'
therefore, *'happens'* will be the correct option.

> Everything in life, even events that seem insignificant when they
>   occur, **happens** for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that sentence as written is inherently ambiguous, and should use “happens” but with one significant change that removes this ambiguity.

> Everything in life, ***including*** events that seem insignificant when they
>   occur, ***happens*** for a reason.

“Everything” is a singular pronoun, and the sentence makes it clear that the (plural) events are a part of it.